# Onclick to store in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to store in array using onclick on checkbox input code is shown below :

```
function CheckBoxShortList(x,y,z)
    {
        var slide = '';
        var arr = [];
        arr.push = x + ',' + y + ',' + z;    
        console.log(arr);
    }
```

CheckBox code is below :

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="CheckBoxShortList('@item.Cid','@item.Hid','@k');">
```

It shows current value on `console.log(arr)` which is okay but if i use `console.log(arr.length)` then it is 0 not incrementing.
Also i want to remove from array as i uncheck the input box.*

Comment: move ``var arr = []` outside of your function

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1):

[`Array.prototype.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) is a **method**. You have to call it, instead of assigning a value to it:

```js
function CheckBoxShortList(x,y,z) {
    var slide = '';
    var arr = [];
    arr.push(x + ',' + y + ',' + z); // length is 1
    console.log(arr);
    console.log('Length:', arr.length);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" onclick="CheckBoxShortList('a','b','c');">
```

This results in an array containing one string: `["a, b, c"]`.

If you want to push the values one by one, do:

```
arr.push(x); // length is 1
arr.push(y); // length is 2
arr.push(z); // length is 3
```

This results in an array containing three values: `["a", "b", "c"]`.

For removing it, use `Array.prototype.pop`:

```
arr.push(x); // length is 1
arr.push(y); // length is 2
arr.push(z); // length is 3
arr.pop();   // length is 2
arr.pop();   // length is 1
```

Comment: can you give me a example sir

Comment: What should the result look like?

Comment: that is showing but can i see its count and length which is returning 0.

Comment: actually its like i want to insert inside array onclick checkbox then pass the array to server.

Answer (score 0):

define you array outside the function and fire your event `onchange()` instead of `onclick()`

```js
 
    
    
    var arr = [];
    function CheckBoxShortList(x,y,z) {
        if($('#test').is(":checked")){
          var slide = '';
          arr.push(x + ',' + y + ',' + z);    
          console.log(arr);
        }else{
          arr.pop(x + ',' + y + ',' + z);
          console.log(arr);
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="test" type="checkbox" onchange="CheckBoxShortList('@item.Cid','@item.Hid','@k');">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually just use Array's slice function on an arguments object, and it will convert it into a standard JavaScript array

```js
function CheckBoxShortList() {

    var arr = []; // whatever your array

    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments); // array

    arr.push(args.join(','));    // string you push

    console.log(arr); // show o/p

    console.log(arr.length); // it shows 1 because you are pushing only one element to array
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" onclick="CheckBoxShortList('a','b','c');">
```

Comment: Sir that is true but my input checkbox is dynamic upto 30 list i want to add these 30 in the array.

Comment: @RajatShetty doesn't matter even if you input `CheckBoxShortList('a','b','c',1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30);` like this it will join each element with comma

Answer (score 0):

Earlier you were storing your values in an object named `arr` in its field named `push`.
Considering your values to be stored as a string in an array we call upon push method on it.

```
var arr = [];
function CheckBoxShortList(x,y,z)
    {
        var slide = '';

        arr.push(x + ',' + y + ',' + z);    
        console.log(arr);
    }
```

Considering your values to be stored separately

```
var arr = [];
function CheckBoxShortList(x,y,z)
    {
        var slide = '';

        arr.push(x);
        arr.push(y);
        arr.push(z);
        console.log(arr);
    }
```

Comment: that is true if on single call it will store those three values but after i click again then what old values are gone new are created over the array.

Comment: @RajatShetty Do you want to flush out prev values?

Answer (score 0):

As PeterMader said, `Array.prototype.push` is a method, it has to be passed the argument like this:

```
arr.push(x + ',' + y + ',' + z);
```

If you wish to know why your code did not generate an error before it is because arrays are (obviously) objects in JavaScript. So when you says `array.attr = value`, the array object gets assigned an attribute `attr` whose value is `value`. In your case the array was assigned an attribute called `push` that stored your values, however, the array itself as a list was still empty which is why the array length was zero since additional attributes do not change the length of the array.

If you wish to add the items separately, you can use `.push()` for each item alone. You can also add another array to the original array using `arr.contact(otherArray)`.

Hope that helps a little.

Comment: Sir my input checkbox is dynamic say 30 are these in the list i want to add 30 of these in the array like this method "arr.push(x + ',' + y + ',' + z);"

Comment: Hi Rajat, I updated my answer. You can push each item alone. Conversely, if you have several items in a different array you can use `concat()` to add the array to `arr`. Again let me know if I can be of more help to you.

Comment: Thank you Y2H i'll try this method